# How can post and populate todos (no relational array) inside service? todos: no relational nested array. service: model's object

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm trying to insert one document called "service" from Collection "services". I want see todos inside service object, but I only see todo id. May you help me, please?

this is my code:

the schema:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const serviceSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  pricePerHour: Number,
  todos: [
    {
      name: String,
      description: String,
      isDone: Boolean
    }
  ],
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date
});

mongoose.model("services", serviceSchema);
```

that's my post services

```js
app.post("/api/services", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, description, pricePerHour, todos } = req.body;

  const service = new Service({
    name,
    description,
    pricePerHour,
    todos: [
      {
        name: todos.name,
        description: todos.description,
        isDone: todos.isDone
      }
    ]
  });

  try {
    let newService = await service.save();

    res.status(201).send(newService);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.name === "MongoError") {
      res.status(409).send(err.message);
    }

    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

As you see, I only see the todos id inside each service.

So, how can I post a service with no relational nested array and see every content from todos array inside each service object?

Comment: Can you give us a sample req.body?

Comment: {
    "_id": "5dabd03ec4605b1ea4aa3c22",
    "name": "service 3",
    "description": "maintenance",
    "pricePerHour": 855,
    "todos": [
        {
            "_id": "5dabd03ec4605b1ea4aa3c23"
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: you need to send name, description and isDone in your req.body todos

Comment: I updated the answer to show how your req.body must be like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your req.body structure is the same as Service model schema, you construct your service object in the post route like this:

```
  const service = new Service({
    name,
    description,
    pricePerHour,
    todos
  });
```

And your req.body must be like this to work:

```
{
  "name": "service 3",
  "description": "maintenance",
  "pricePerHour": 855,
  "todos": [{ "name": "todo 1", "description": "description 1", "isDone": true },
            { "name": "todo 2", "description": "description 2", "isDone": false}
  ]
}
```